# React16 Two components communicating

Tags: reactjs, react-16

ReactJS Two components communicating, in angular, we are simply using service best way, but here I am new in react 16.

Comment: Depends where the components are in relation to each other in the tree: (1) pass props down, (2) use Context API (3) use a shared store solution like redux or mobx

Comment: I want to share my login details all our component, in angular7 we have services best way here which one is the best way in react 16. please help me thanks advance

Comment: *we are simply using service* - that's only one of the ways. Another way is to communicate through common parent. That's the way you usually use in React. Another one is to communicate via global state - Redux or context API.

Comment: React is just the view layer and leaves this up to you. The most popular solution is `redux` + `react-redux` packages, many tutorials on that, it is a little tricky for first timers to setup and get used to. Otherwise `mobx` + `mobx-react` is probably the second most popular, which uses observables so might be a bit closer to Angular paradigm.

Comment: Thank you so much, for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two components in react can communicate in following ways

**Parent -> Child Component** via props

**Child -> Parent** via callback

**Child -> Child** via using their closet parent component

eg:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
       name: "John Doe"
      }
      this.changeName = this.changeName.bind(this)
    }
   changeName(newName) {
     this.setState({
       name: newName
     })
   }

    render() {
       return (
           <div>
               // passing data from parent component to child component using props
               // name={this.state.name} changeName={this.changeName}
               <Child name={this.state.name} changeName={this.changeName} />
               <SecondChild name={this.state.name} />
           </div>
         )

      }
 }

 function Child(props) {
   return (
      <div>
         <h1>My name in Child Component is: {props.name} </h1>
         // passing data from child component to parent component using Callback
         // onClick={() => props.changeName('Jeremy Smith')}
         <button onClick={() => props.changeName('Jeremy Smith')}>Change Name</button>
         // when button is clicked "Jeremy Smith" is passed to parent component and 
         // from their passed to both Child and SecondChild components
         // this way we communicate between two child components
      </div>
    )
 }

 function SecondChild(props) {
   return <h1>My Name in Second Child Component is: {props.name}</h1> 
 }
```

In addition

You can also use React Context API for passing data down to Child Components.

Or use state management library like redux for creating single shared store and pass required data to components.

Comment: it's my pleasure